# Issue with the identity of a COM+ application

Tags: com

I am now facing a very strange issue. One of our product installers registers numerous COM DLLs during the installation of the  product. Subsequently, this creates COM+ applications under Administrative tools --> Component Services --> COM+ applications.

One of the COM+ applications is created during the install to run under NETWORK SERVICE  account. However, at times , it has been observed that the identity of this COM+ application is set to interactive. I am using a msi based installer. The windows installer log files clearly state that the COM+ application was set to run under NETWORK SERVICE account.
We use our own custom code to create this COM+ application. This issue is not reproducible at will. However, it does happen on some environments.

Either of the two things is happening:

1. There is a bug in the installer code which is causing this
2. There is something outside of install which is causing this.

I need to determine the root cause of this behavior. Upon carrying out some research on the web, I have come across the following two articles:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926098
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/06/19/tracing-in-com-and-complus.aspx

These two articles talk about how diagnostic logging can be enabled for COM+ components. However, I am not really sure if they will be of use to me , as i need to accurately pin point as to what is changing the identity of  the COM+ component to INTERACTIVE USER.

The other major disadvantage with this logging is that the .etl files output are in a binary format and can only be decoded by contacting Microsoft with the help of so-called .tmf files.

Questions:

1. What are the other options available to me to diagnose this issue?
2. Can I format the .etl files without the help of Microsoft?
3. Is there any mechanism in place just like process monitor, which could monitor all the events within COM+?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help or not but http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/etl says you can use tracerpt.exe (located in your system32/syswow64 directory) to produce reports from the etl files.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I think i have used this and it turned out that it still requires the .tmf files.

Comment: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732700(v=ws.10).aspx) has examples at the bottom of the page; one shows "tracerpt logfile.etl -o logdmp.xml -of XML -lr -summary logdmp.txt -report logrpt.xml" which will generate a text summary file and an XML report file.  I found a small .etl file in my %windir%\logfiles directory, and when I ran the above command on it, I wound up with a pair of xml files and a text summary.  I didn't see any .tmf files anywhere.  (Of course it's always possible that whatever files you're seeing are different in some way than the one I looked at.)